# Sketching level sets of functions with more than two variables

Tags: vector-analysis

I was recently asked the question:

Sketch the level set:

x - y + z + 2 = c                  where c = 0,1,2,3

How would I go about doing this? As you can see the function f(x,y,z) has already been set to some constant c. But I have no idea as to how I would sketch this. (Perhaps rearranging for z?)

Comment: Yes, these level sets are parallel 2D planes in 3D space. Solving for $z$ will let you think of them as plots of linear functions $z=f(x,y)$.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Karl, I believe I understand what you're saying. So starting with z = y - x - 2 + c (correct?) and then substituting in the corresponding values of c given? So would one just then plot curve of y - x -2 (for c = 0 case)? Or am I missing something?